# Unable to trigger if block in wordle clone

Tags: node.js, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I followed PedroTech's guide for a Wordle Clone to practice React, which I really enjoy. I've mostly had no issues and have made some additions myself but am having a hell of a time getting my gameOver condition to trigger on a win (guessing the correct word). It triggers correctly on a loss (6 guesses without the right word). The issue would seem at first blush to be a casing mismatch between the correct word from the word bank and the current word being concatted in the for loop, but upon logging each I am getting identical strings. I have tried everything in my toolbelt at this point and am at a loss.

Here is where the correct word and states are set. The correct word is set from a lowercase bank using use effect and is logged upon comp mount. I know it is correct because I am getting my letter colors to fill correctly upon guess. I will post an image to give a better idea of what I'm looking at.

```
`function App() {
  const [board, setBoard] = useState(emptyBoard);
  const [wordSet, setWordSet] = useState(new Set());
  const [currentGuess, setCurrentGuess] = useState({ attempt: 0, letterPosition: 0 });
  const [gamesWon, setGamesWon] = useState(0);
  const [soupInfo, setSoupInfo] = useState([]);
  const [soupPic, setSoupPic] = useState(null);
  const [userPersist, setUserPersist] = useState(false);
  const [validWord, setValidWord] = useState('');
  const [disabledLetters, setDisabledLetters] = useState([]);
  const [gameOver, setGameOver] = useState({ gameOver: false, guessedWord: false })
  const [correctWord, setCorrectWord] = useState('');
  const [playerPosition, setPlayerPosition] = useState(1);
  // let [currentWord, setCurrentWord] = useState('');
  let [soupIndex, setSoupIndex] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    genWordSet().then((words) => {
      setWordSet(words.wordSet);
      setCorrectWord(words.todaysWord);
    });
  }, []);`
```

Here is an image of the correct word being recognized letter by letter:

[soup-seeker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9tP8.jpg)

Here is my onEnter() function that recognizes keydown input of a 5-letter word. This is where the gameOver state should change upon correctWord and currentWord being matched:

```
  const onEnter = () => {
    if (currentGuess.letterPosition !== 5) return;

    let currentWord = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      // setCurrentWord(board[currentGuess.attempt][i].toString())
      currentWord += board[currentGuess.attempt][i].toLowerCase();
    }

    console.log(currentWord);
    console.log(correctWord);
    console.log(typeof currentWord);
    console.log(typeof correctWord);
    // + `\r`
    //not sure why this \r is appearing in the word set but can just concatenate 
    if (wordSet.has(currentWord.toLowerCase() + `\r`)) {
      setCurrentGuess({ attempt: currentGuess.attempt + 1, letterPosition: 0 });
      console.log(currentWord)
      console.log(correctWord);
    } else {
      setValidWord('Not null');
    } if (currentWord === correctWord) {
      setGameOver({ gameOver: true, guessedWord: true });
      return;
    };
    if (currentGuess.attempt === 5) {
      setGameOver({ gameOver: true, guessedWord: false })
      return;
    };
    //increase the array index w attempt; reset position in array to start for next guess 
  };
```

I have a tried lower casing the current word in the if condition but it doesn't seem to do anything, and they are both registering as a lowercase strings anyways.

Could anyone help me out? I'm pretty new to this so my guess is I'm missing something really obvious. Usually I try to solve things myself but this one has me really stumped.

Thank you.

Comment: What are the values of your logs in the console

Comment: The current values read as: pixie, pixie, string, string. In this scenario pixie is the word selected from the word bank in log and pixie is the word entered and concatenated in the for loop. It may be easier to see in the screenshot

Comment: add an else to this ```if (currentWord === correctWord) {
      setGameOver({ gameOver: true, guessedWord: true });
      return;
    };``` and log the currentWord vs the correctWord there, also check thier length, maybe you are adding a space somewhere